# LFENCE is really useless vs. Spectre #2?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture

Does anyone know why the LFENCE instruction is recommended to stop speculative execution in case of Spectre #1 (bounds check bypass/out-of-bound read), but is useless in case of Spectre #2 (branch target injection)? Both these Spectre vulnerabilities are related to speculative execution and are exploiting the branch predictor. As I understand in first case the generic predictor is involved and in second the indirect call predictor. Will it useful if I'm starting to use LFENCE to prevent speculative execution based on indirect call predictor to mitigate Spectre #2?

Answer (score 10):

From the [Spectre paper](https://spectreattack.com/spectre.pdf)

> 7  Mitigation Options
>
> > The  conditional  branch  vulnerability  can  be
> >     mitigated if  speculative  execution  can  be  halted  on 
> >     potentially- sensitive execution paths.

What this means is that if you have code like

```
if (security critical check)
  execute critical code
else 
  do not execute critical code
```

then you need to place the serializing instruction *right before* the security critical code:

```
if (security critical check)
  lfence
  execute critical code
else 
  do not execute critical code
```

to avoid speculation on the check to potentially leak information.

In Spectre #2, the attacker controls the "entry point" where the CPU speculates the execution will continue. Putting

```
lfence
critical code
```

does not help, because the attacker doesn't have to cause prediction to target the `lfence`, they can make it target the `critical code` directly.

Comment: Obviously this can be fixed by interspersing the critical code with `lfence` statements so that an attacker cannot avoid its execution. This however has a hefty performance cost.

Comment: @Johan As far as I understand it, the problem is that the attacker can choose the gadget in all of the victim's executable code. Maybe writing "critical code" was somewhat imprecise: The attacker needs a sequence that accesses memory, then uses the loaded value as part of an address calculation leading to another memory access. To prevent the information leak, the mitigation would have to put a serializing instruction between every pair of such gadgetable memory accesses. A tall order, particularly on a variable-length instruction encoding architecture like x86.

Comment: In case of Spectre #2, as I understand, an attacker needs a gadget from victim's process that should contain jmp/call/ret, because, in otherwise, he can't expoit indirect branch predictor. But, frankly speaking, I can't imagine how that call/jmp/ret from victim's process can lead to execution of attacker's code... Do u have a simple code snippet for explanation? @EOF.

Comment: @ArtemBaranov The branch prediction machinery in the CPU is *shared*. The attacker can train the branch target prediction by executing indirect jumps in *their own process*. The attacker then requires an indirect branch to occur in the victim't process, but modern object-oriented code performs plenty of indirect branches.

Comment: @EOF When you say "the mitigation would have to put a serializing instruction between every pair of such gadgetable memory accesses". Where exactly would this happen? Do the Kernels need to be updated for this, is this something that needs to be changed per software or can this be fixed with the upcoming microcode patches?

Comment: @TomK. The approach to Spectre #2 is different, precisely because putting in serializing instructions doesn't work. Instead, the branch target predictor can be invalidated (using new instructions or special purpose machine specific registers) or avoided (using a return instruction instead of an ordinary indirect branch).

Comment: @EOF Intel says that lfence is useful in retpoline construction, when you want to mitigate Spectre #2.

https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/1d/46/Retpoline-A-Branch-Target-Injection-Mitigation.pdf

Comment: @ArtemBaranov Thank you, that paper is a good read. Interestingly, the `lfence` in retpolines is executed *only speculatively*. I wonder whether it could be replaced with `ud2`, like Intel recommends placing `ud2` after an indirect branch to tell the processor that no fall-through will occur.